# Apply function n-times, using output of last as input of next

Tags: python

For example, when traversing multiple levels up a hierarchy using `dirname` I typically do this.

```
grandparent = os.path.dirname(__file__)
grandparent = os.path.dirname(grandparent)
```

Or, in case of more levels.

```
grandparent =  = os.path.dirname(__file__)
for x in xrange(5):
  grandparent = os.path.dirname(grandparent)
```

But I wonder if there's a less verbose method of doing this?

Such as

```
grandparent = y(5, os.path.dirname, __file__)
```

Where `y` is the mysterious function I'm looking for.

And if not, what would such a function be called?

Comment: This isn't built into the standard library, but you clearly have an idea how to implement such a function. It's difficult to write in the generic case because you can't currently handle functions with multiple parameters and return values.

Comment: Do you just want a function that gives a grandparent @ certain level? or rather a parent @ certain level? Or is this a more generic requirement?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I modified the example to support arbitrary arguments, but yeah, multiple return values would be more difficult.

Answer (score 3):

What about defining such *higher order function* yourself:

```
def repeat (f, x, n) :
    for i in range(n):
        x = f(x)
    return x
```

With `f` the function you wish to call, `x` the first input in the sequence, and `n` the number of times you wish to call this.

You can then call it for instance with:

```
>>> repeat(lambda x: x**2,2,3)
256
>>> repeat(os.path.dirname,'/home/kommusoft/testfolder/sqldump', 2)
'/home/kommusoft'
```

If you however plan to walk to the root of a directory, using a large number of repetitions is *not safe*: you never know that some user has made a cascade of *over nine thousand* directories.

Comment: @MarcusOttosson: well the point is of course that you can reuse `repeat` and furthermore; as is always with utility methods, it's better to encapsulate functionality in one function such that you can easily debug that function, make it more efficient; do parameter checking (perhaps you want to throw an exception if `n < 0`); etc. But I agree it is a minor contribution.